# How to get a json file from raw folder?

Tags: android, json, jackson, inputstream

I want to use my user.json which is in my raw folder to get a new File :

```
// read from file, convert it to user class
User user = mapper.readValue(new File(**R.raw.user**), User.class);
```

I found that InputStream can do it :

```
InputStream ins = res.openRawResource(
                        getResources().getIdentifier("raw/user",
                                "raw", getPackageName()));
```

Is there a better way to do it, directly with my json file ID ?

Comment: what's wrong with `openRawResource(R.raw.user)` ?

Comment: nothing wrong, I just want to know if I can use something different like R.raw instead of InputStream to get my new File

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ObjectMapper.readValue` also take `InputStream` as source . Get `InputStream` using `openRawResource` method from json file and pass it to `readValue` :

```
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.user);
User user = mapper.readValue(in, User.class);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.json_file);
Writer writer = new StringWriter();
char[] buffer = new char[1024];
try {
    Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
    int n;
    while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
} finally {
    is.close();
}

String jsonString = writer.toString();
```

Comment: assets and raw are different folders, aren't they ?

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin way :

```
val raw = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.posts)
        val writer: Writer = StringWriter()
        val buffer = CharArray(1024)
        raw.use { rawData ->
            val reader: Reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(rawData, "UTF-8"))
            var n: Int
            while (reader.read(buffer).also { n = it } != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n)
            }
        }

        val jsonString = writer.toString()
```